# Threads will not close off after program completion

Tags: python-3.x, python-multithreading

I have a script that receives temperature data via using requests. Since I had to make multiple requests (around 13000) I decided to explore the use of multi-threading which I am new at.

The programs work by grabbing longitude/latitude data from a csv file and then makes a request to retrieve the temperature data.

The problem that I am facing is that the script does not finish fully when the last temperature value is retrieved.

Here is the code. I have shortened so it is easy to see what I am doing:

```
num_threads = 16
q = Queue(maxsize=0)

def get_temp(q):
    while not q.empty():
        work = q.get()
        if work is None:
            break
         ## rest of my code here  
    q.task_done()
```

At main:

```
def main():

    for o in range(num_threads):
        logging.debug('Starting Thread %s', o)
        worker = threading.Thread(target=get_temp, args=(q,))
        worker.setDaemon(True)
        worker.start()

    logging.info("Main Thread Waiting")
    q.join()

    logging.info("Job complete!")
```

I do not see any errors on the console and temperature is being successfully being written to another file. I have a tried running a test csv file with only a few longitude/latitude references and the script seems to finish executing fine.

So is there a way of shedding light as to what might be happening in the background? I am using Python 3.7.3 on PyCharm 2019.1 on Linux Mint 19.1.

Answer (score 0):

the `.join()` function waits for all threads to join before continuing to the next line